# Replace query placeholder with single-quoted value

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have the simple query in Go:

```
import "database/sql"

Db, err := sql.Open(...)
p1 := "string param"
Db.QueryRow("select * from some_func(?)", p1)
```

The `some_func` accepts string param. In terms of PGsql it is a single-quoted text: `'some val'`.

To achieve passing single quoted param I did the following: `Db.QueryRow("select * from some_func('?')", p1)`. I’ve wrapped `?` with single quotes. But I’m getting error: 1 parameter is passed when expecting 0

Comment: Those quotes you provided are not valid Go syntax, please provide code that's valid. https://play.golang.org/p/StkVcAWayPu

Comment: Not sure what db driver you're using but a placeholder in postgres looks like this: `$1` for first param, `$2` for second, and so on. `?` placeholders are mysql syntax. Using `?` with the `lib/pq`, if that's what you're using, driver is not gonna work.

Comment: As a workaround I can achieve that by using `fmt..Sprintf`, but it’s not SQL injection safe, because I got param from for the `some_func` from user. If I would have separate sql escaping function in addition to raw `fmt.Sprintf` then may be I could be statisfied by such workaround

Comment: Finally, most db drivers evaluate your parameters and substitute the placeholders according the their type automatically, meaning that you don't have to worry about putting quotes around it yourself, that's the driver's job.

Comment: Given your update, and assuming you're using `lib/pq`, you should do this `Db.QueryRow("select * from some_func($1)", p1)`.

Comment: @mkopriva I've also tried with $1 placeholders. It's also not work, I think the db driver not properly guess params for `some_func`

Comment: Please provide the error you get when you use `$1`.

Comment: Please also provide what driver you are using.

Comment: @mkopriva you were right about `$1` PostgresSQL placeholders. I carefully refactored the code and the problem is gone. Now params is properly quoted. I was getting error when just replacing `?` with `$`. THX!!!

Comment: Different error message than the duplicate but the same underlying problem: PostgreSQL uses numbered placeholders natively, not positional question marks.

Comment: `res, err := DB.Exec("COPY spark_phones (inn, phone) FROM $1", csvName)` 
@mkopriva what about that query?? I'm getting error, `syntax error at $1`

Comment: @Varp try `DB.Exec(\`EXECUTE "COPY spark_phones (inn, phone) FROM " || $1\`, csvName)` use backtics for the execute string so that you don't have to escape the inner quotes.